# Night Shift makes display colder before making it warmer

Tags: display, color, night-shift

I have Night Shift set to enable at a custom time (the automatic "Sunset to Sunrise" option enabled too early for my taste). When Night Shift enables, the display dims and gets a lot cooler (bluer) in the space of a few seconds. It then gradually warms up to the correct nighttime temperature.

This may help to understand the problem – the dotted line is the path the temperature should take:

[image: Graph]

If I disable and re-enable "Turn On Until Tomorrow" the displays quickly adjust to the correct warm temperature. I have the temperature slider head set just past the midpoint line on the slider, so the displays are significantly warmer than normal. This makes sense – macOS only adjusts temperature gradually when Night Shift is enabled by the clock.

In order to match the temperature of the displays with and without Night Shift enabled, I have to set the slider to ~33%:

[image: Night Shift slider]

Both of my monitors are colour-calibrated Adobe RGB displays. Both monitors exhibit the same issue. I have tried switching to sRGB and other colour profiles but the issue persists.

The computer is a Mac Pro 2019 with macOS Catalina 10.15.4.

Answer (score 3):

I've have this issue too for a while now. It is pretty annoying. The only fix I've found is manually toggling it OFF and then toggling ON again after the "Sunrise to Sunset" automation kicks in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue. Macbook Pro 13 2020 (intel).

If the Lid is opened (no matter if external display is connected) - nightshift works as expected with smooth transition to warm colors.

But in clamshell mode (when Laptop lid is closed and I'm attached to external screen) screen becomes suddenly blue at the moment of sunset and then in 5-10 min it gets warmer.

It happened with me on some of the Monterey's update (12.4 or 12.5, I suppose).
Now I'm on Ventura 13.1 - the issue is still here.

Moreover, I did one experiment:
I took my wife's Mac with Monterey. The version was 12.3. I've checked night shift (in all modes: laptop/extended display/clamshell) - everything was OK (no blue sudden blue tints on start time of the schedule, everything is smooth).
Then I updated it to the latest Monterey available 12.6.2 and ... now it has the same issue :)

So, it seems that there was a "security" patch for all OS from Catalina to Monterey that caused this issue. And it is still here in the latest Ventura

Comment: I updated to Ventura and the issue persists for me too. It's interesting that it only appears to affect external displays. Is your external display an Apple model or third-party?

Comment: It's third party via USB-C dock

Comment: I agree that the problem only happens for me with an external display, but it always happens, even if the MBP itself is open. In that case, night shift starts and the MBP gets warm, while the external shifts blue.